# Wordpress contact plugin not working correctly in my website

Tags: wordpress

I use contact page 7 plugin for word press. I have configured it correctly from the admin panel. But in my website, when I click on submit then the following message appears.

> Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the
>   administrator by another method.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Please rephrase your question so we can understand what it is you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two causes for this.

You are not using correct email in "from" or in "to" email, perhaps you are using [subject] which could be empty or empty shortcode (remove any shortcode in from,to,subjects fileds) in "from" or in "to".

The first is actual mail server trouble, where email cannot be sent, in this case you can use SMTP plugin to configure it properly or contact your server provider.